# 'unique_together' refers to the non-existent field

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

When trying to use `unique_together` on two foreign key constraints, I get the following error:

```
CommandError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
main.AuthorTag: (models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the non-existent field 'author'.
main.AuthorTag: (models.E012) 'unique_together' refers to the non-existent field 'tag'.
```

On the following table

```
class AuthorTag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('tag', 'author',),)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(TagIndex, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
```

The same example seems to work here: [Unique foreign key pairs with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522648/unique-foreign-key-pairs-with-django?rq=1)
But I can't figure out why I get this error

EDIT:
changing `unique_together = (('tag', 'author',),)` to `unique_together = (('tag', 'author'))` give me the same error. as well as moving the meta class below the field declarations.

Comment: Moving the meta class has no effect unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the trailing commas, making the code to:

```
class AuthorTag(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['tag', 'author']

    tag = models.ForeignKey(TagIndex, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Made it work. I am unsure why.

Comment: I just faced the same problem, It is because of the trailing commas. 

unique_together = ('tag', 'author') still works for me.

Comment: In my case, the problem was due to a syntax error where I accidentally added a comma at the end of the foreign key instantiation: `some_key = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE),` (notice the comma at the end, this syntax mistake produced the same error.)

Comment: My case was the comma too!! Incredible that this does not throw an error